# How can I add a menu to the application in the dock?

Tags: swift, macos, window, dock

When you right click on the application in the dock a context menu pops up. How can I add a menu item to this?

As for example with Safari you got New window in the context menu.

Comment: Check out the [Dock Tile Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/intro/dockintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH1-TP1)

Answer (score 11):

**Adding Static Menu Items With a Nib File**

If your application needs to add static items to the application’s Dock tile’s menu, you can provide those items in a nib file. To do this, perform the following steps.

1. Launch Interface Builder.
2. Create a new nib file for your menu.
3. Create a menu that includes the items you wish to add to the menu.
4. Connect the `dockMenu` outlet of the file’s owner (which by default is `NSApplication`) to your menu.
5. Add the nib name to the `Info.plist`, using the key `AppleDockMenu`. The nib name is specified without an extension.

**Dynamically Adding Menu Items With the Application Delegate**

An application can also provide items dynamically to your application’s Dock tile’s menu. To do this, your application’s delegate object provides a `applicationDockMenu:` method. This method returns a NSMenu object that provides all the custom menu items you wish to add to the menu. If you also provided a menu using a nib file (see [Adding Static Menu Items With a Nib File](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW6)), any menu returned by your delegate replaces the menu provided in the nib file.

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW7)

Comment: Is there any documentation/tutorial on how to add a dynamic menu while the application is shutdown. Similar to the jump list menu, Xcode has to projects previously opened?